# SQL SERVER 2008 Connection String using Java throws an Exception's Message

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, connection-string

SQL SERVER 2008 Connection String using Java throws the following exception

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"

Please Update!

Comment: And what is the exception/error message?

Comment: I have reviewed my question and made changes accordingly

Comment: `@Shahid Ghafoor` What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2505) and extract the jar file to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the connector's jar to your application's classpath.